# Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n\cos n\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

> Calculate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n\cos n\alpha, a\in\mathbb{R}, \alpha\in\mathbb{R},|a|<1$$

This is what I tried:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n\cos\alpha &= \Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{i\alpha n}e^{n\ln a}\right)\\ &= \Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{n(i\alpha+\ln a)}\right)\\ &=\Re\left(\frac{1}{1-e^{i\alpha+\ln a}}\right)\text{ [Geometric progression] }\\ &=\frac{1}{1-a\cos\alpha}\end{align}$$

However, the answer is supposed to be:

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n\cos n\alpha=\frac{a(\cos\alpha-a)}{1-2a\cos\alpha+a^2}$$

What am I missing?

Comment: You dropped $ia\sin\alpha$.

Comment: And how do you take the real part of that? (Sorry this is my first time working with complex numbers, I don't know how to work with them). I still don't see how to get the correct answer

Comment: There is a rule for the quotient of two complex numbers...

Comment: There's no need to write $a=e^{\ln a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{split}\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n \cos{(n\alpha)} =&  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{e}^{n \ln a} \operatorname{Re}\left( \operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}n\alpha}\right)= \operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{e}^{n \ln a} \operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}n\alpha}\right)\\
=& \operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{e}^{n \ln a+\operatorname{i}n\alpha}\right)\\
=&\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \operatorname{e}^{n \left(\ln a+\operatorname{i}\alpha\right)}\right)\\
=&\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\operatorname{e}^{\ln a+\operatorname{i}\alpha}\right)^n\right)\\
=&\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(a\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\alpha}\right)^n\right)\\
=&\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{a\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\alpha}}{1-a\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\alpha}}\right)\\
=&\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{a\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\alpha}}{1-a\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\alpha}} \cdot\frac{1-a\operatorname{e}^{-\operatorname{i}\alpha}}{1-a\operatorname{e}^{-\operatorname{i}\alpha}}\right)\\
=&\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{a\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\alpha}-a^2}{1-a(\operatorname{e}^{\operatorname{i}\alpha}+\operatorname{e}^{-\operatorname{i}\alpha})+a^2} \right)\\
=&\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{a(\cos \alpha + \operatorname{i} \sin \alpha)-a^2}{1-2a\cos \alpha+a^2} \right)\\
=&\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{a\cos \alpha -a^2 }{1-2a\cos \alpha+a^2}+ \operatorname{i} \frac{ a \sin \alpha}{1-2a\cos \alpha+a^2} \right)\\
=&\frac{a\cos \alpha -a^2 }{1-2a\cos \alpha+a^2}\\
\end{split} $$

Answer (score 2):

$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} r^{n }$ is not $\frac   1{1-r}$. It is $\frac  r {1-r}$.  Also your calculation of the real part at the end is wrong as pointed out by metamorphy.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^{n}cos{(an)}$=$\Re\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{n(i\alpha+\ln a)}\right)\\$=$\Re\ (e^{ia+ln(a)} \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{n(i\alpha+\ln a)}\right))\\$= $Re\ (\frac{e^{ia+lna}}{1-e^{ia+lna}})$=$Re\ (\frac{acos(a)+aisin(a)}{(1-acos(a))-iasin(a))})$=$\frac{acos(a)(a-acos(a))-a^{2}sin^{2}(a)}{(1-acos(a))^{2}+a^2(sin^{2}(a))}$=$\frac{a^{2}cos(a)-a^{2}(cos^{2}(a)+sin^2{a})}{1-2acos(a)+a^{2}(cos^{2}(a)+sin^{2}(a))}$=$\frac{a(cos(a)-a)}{a-2acos(a)+a^{2}}$.